# Credible historic description of how the daily life was for the middle-class during the financial crisis of 1929

Tags: economy

I am trying to find out how life could change for the middle-class today if we had a high-impact financial crisis. Please help-me / let me know if this question could be rephrased better.

Comment: No more iPhones. Oh The Horrorz!

Comment: The subject line is fine but the main body is not.  Speculation on what could happen is not really a good fit for this site.  However, asking about specifics of the 1930 crisis is fine.  Note that any comparison would be spurious at best since geopolitics and socio-economics factors are so different.

Comment: I agree with Sardathrion, you are asking one thing in the title but the description is something else.  It'd be better to note you are researching middle class life in 1929, and you might want to limit geography as it will be different according to country.  I would think you could find much of this from reading newspapers of the time at your local library, or even magazines of the day for housewives or general interest magazines.

Comment: Little of what you will learn will be applicable to 2011.

Comment: This question was closed because it does not fit within the guidelines for a SE site. The question cannot be answered with facts or references. It can only be answered by opinion or speculation, and that causes it to fall outside the realm of acceptability.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading the novel "City Boy," by Herman Wouk. It was set in 1928, just before the 1929 crisis, and gave a description of middle class life going into (but not after) the 1929 crisis.

For an account of life during the 1930s itself, the "classic" is John Steinbeck's "Grapes of Wrath," about how formerly middle class people fell into poverty.